# How to use QDateTime::fromString?

Tags: qt, qdatetime

I now, the question sounds rather silly, but I just can't get it to work. Worst example:

```
QString time_format = "yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss";
QDateTime a = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QString as = a.toString(time_format);

qDebug() << as; // print "2014-07-16  17:47:04"

QDateTime b;
b.fromString(as,time_format);
assert(b.isValid()); // fails
```

I create a valid QDatetime, make a string out of it (that is correct) and try to turn it into a QDatetime again (using the same time_format-string). But suddenly, the string can't be parsed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fromString` is a static function that returns the date; so you need to do:

```
QDateTime b = QDateTime::fromString(as,time_format);
```

in your code `b` never chaged from its default initialized state

Comment: Oh. Sometimes one (me) should read the manual better. Thanks, that solved it!

Comment: This *might* fail to work in case your system language is something other than English.

Answer (score 3):

```
QString as = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: In my case it didn't work with the ":" but when replaced with "-" it did. Whyever, just in case someone can't get it work as well.